# Automatically resize text box in Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, shortcuts

I want to know if there's a keyboard shortcut that will resize the text box to show all of my text in Illustrator similar to the way that <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>CMD</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> works in InDesign?

So if my text can't fit as in the image below, I'd just enter a keyboard shortcut that will reveal all of the text. [image]

Answer (score 2):

I am a shortcut maniac, and I also miss this shortcut.
You can always use the Area Type Options... or set it up previously in preferences as showed below.

[image]

Comment: This kind of works, but I don't find that it does the same thing as in Indesign, which is unfortunate. Thanks though!

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, there isn't a shortcut (to my knowledge) to conform a frame to its contents in Illustrator. If line breaks are not an issue, my recommendation would be to forego the frames altogether, and simply use text objects.

Comment: I actually had never played around with this. This works for short pieces of text for sure!

Answer (score 0):

I found a shortcut that does the same thing as Type > Area Type Options > Auto Size. Double click the handle that extends out from the bottom of area text box.

[image: double click handle to auto-size area text box]
[image: click and drag arrow to resize]

Here's where I found this trick/more information: https://millo.co/overlooked-illustrator-feature-first-now-saves-time-headaches